# Can you automatically delete rows of data in a data frame based off of multiple requirements in R?

Tags: r

Is it possible to look at variables in a data frame and delete some rows based off of certain conditions? If I have the table:

| Number | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE |
| 1 | FALSE |
| 2 | FALSE |
| 2 | FALSE |
| 3 | FALSE |
| 3 | TRUE |
| 4 | FALSE |
| 4 | FALSE |
| 5 | TRUE |
| 5 | FALSE |

I want to have exactly one row of each number, and I will delete whichever row is false, and if both values in the number are false, then I will just delete one of the rows. This should leave me with the table like

| Number | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE |
| 2 | FALSE |
| 3 | TRUE |
| 4 | FALSE |
| 5 | TRUE |

Is it possible to filter by number then delete the first false value? Or anything similar to that?

Comment: Phrased another way, looks like you want to find if any value, by number, is TRUE; i.e. `aggregate(Value ~ Number, data, any)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `arrange` and then use `distinct` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(Number, !Value) %>%
  distinct(Number, .keep_all = TRUE)

#  Number Value
#1      1  TRUE
#2      2 FALSE
#3      3  TRUE
#4      4 FALSE
#5      5  TRUE
```

`arrange` would keep the `TRUE` values ahead of `FALSE` ones and then we select the 1st row for each `Number`.

---

Another option would be to check for condition in each group.

```
df %>%
  group_by(Number) %>%
  filter(if(any(Value)) Value else row_number() == 1) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Base R translation of your original logic for fun `dat <- dat[order(dat$Number, !dat$Value),]; dat[!duplicated(dat$Number),]`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Number) %>% filter(if(sum(Value == FALSE) == 2) row_number() == 1 else Value == TRUE)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   Number [5]
  Number Value
   <int> <lgl>
1      1 TRUE 
2      2 FALSE
3      3 TRUE 
4      4 FALSE
5      5 TRUE
```